# Prove or disprove: The set of positive operators in L(V) is a subspace of L(V).

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble getting started with this problem.  I've been in and out of my Advanced Linear Algebra Class the last couple weeks due to Mono.  Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you define as a positive operator?

Comment: An operator T in L(V) is called positive if T is self-adjoint and <Tv,v> is greater than or equal to zero for all v in V.